# What will be the output/discharge current of a capacitor?

Tags: power-supply, power, capacitor, solar-cell, supercapacitor

I am planning on doing an experiment where I want to connect a 2V 500mA solar panel to a 25F 2.7V super capacitor and then I will connect it to a 5V output boost converter. I know the capacitor output current formula is

$$i(t)=C \dfrac{dv}{dt}$$

but I am not sure what will be the output voltage and current of the capacitor would be to the boost converter. Another set up would be to connect 4 25F 2.7V capacitors in series and then in parallel to a 1.2 watt solar panel, what would be output V and I in that case? Also please let me know if its a bad idea.
Thank you, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Charging the caps in parallel from the solar cell and discharging them in series to charge your phone is a interesting concept .You will have to be mindfull of peak discharge currents .Some caps have internal resistances of milliohms.

Answer (score 0):

> but I am not sure what will be the output voltage and current of the
>   capacitor would be to the boost converter

**voltage :** output voltage will be the same ass input voltage(2V)

**current :** i = C(dv/dt) = 25(2/time) Will depend upon the load.

**Energy stored in capacitor**=  C * V^2 / 2 = 25*2^ = 100 J or **Watt**(as solar panel is giving 2V )

2V 500mA solar panel will take 100 sec to full charge the 25F 2V capacitor(depends on the sun light and solar panel output)

> Another set up would be to connect 4 25F 2.7V capacitors in series and
>   then in parallel to a 1.2 watt solar panel, what would be output V and
>   I in that case

4 capacitor in series + solar panel 1.2W in parallel? need voltage and current (if solar panel voltage is less than 8V nothing will happen)

**voltage :** 4 * input voltage

**current :** i = C(dv/dt) = C(2/time) Will depend upon the load.

1/C = 1/c1 + 1/c2 + 1/c3 + 1/c4 put C value in above energy capacitor formula.